# How to compare input value with mysql database and then automatically add '0' and '1' if there is no matching data

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to compare my input value with my database. And if the input value is the same as the database value, I want to `print("Data Valid")` . And if it's not the same, I want to add '0' and '1' to the input value.
and automatically compare again the final value with my database and so on.

So I've tried this code :

```
curs = connection.cursor()
    query = """ SELECT * FROM `foo` """

    curs.execute(query)
    result = curs.fetchall()
    inputvalue = input("Input= ")
    temp = False
    for x in result:
        if inputvalue in x:
            temp = True
    if temp:
        print("Data Valid")
    else:
        inputvalue += '0'
        inputvalue += '1'
        if inputvalue in x:
            print(inputvalue)
```

But after I run my code, it seems that it added both '0' and '1' to the value and i want it to be 2 different value.

**If the data is the same as the database**, I want the output to be:

```
inputvalue= 100
Data Valid
```

**And if it's not the same**, I want the output to be:

```
inputvalue= 100
1000
1001
```

And then compare `1000` and `1001` with my database again
and the output will be like this: (if the data match my database)

```
inputvalue= 100
1000
1001
Data Valid
```

and if it's doesn't match:

```
inputvalue= 100
1000
1001
10000
10001
10010
10011
```

Any answer would be appreciated and help me so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little messy. You can try this:

```py
def check(value, result):
    for ele in result:
        if value in ele:
            print('Data Valid')
            return True
    return False

def check_in_list(value_list, result):
    for value in value_list:
        if check(value, result):
            return True
    return False

# refer to your code
curs = connection.cursor()
query = """ SELECT * FROM `foo` """
curs.execute(query)
result = curs.fetchall()
input_value = input("Input= ")

value_list = [input_value]
while True:
    if check_in_list(value_list, result):
        break
    tmp_list = []
    for value in value_list:
        print(value + '0')
        print(value + '1')
        tmp_list.append(value + '0')
        tmp_list.append(value + '1')
    value_list = tmp_list
```

But it has some cons that maybe sometimes it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you so much @LiuChang for your help, your code works perfectly as I wanted!

Comment: But after I tried your code, it seems that it just repeatedly printed '0' instead of '0' and '1'. like this ```300000000000000000000000000001```, can you make the output print both of them like ```3001000100000010011000010000001000```. That will help so much.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I make a mistake about your requirements. I have edited the answer, please have a try. @Frank Kzasch

Comment: It works! Dude, you're a god. Thank you so much for helping me!